# Sprinkler zone and valve identification issue

Tags: irrigation

My sprinkler system has 4 zones that go to 4 valves. 1 goes to the front and 2-3 go to the back. All sprinklers are activated with these 3. However, zone 4 also activates its valve and I hear the water runing. No sprinklers go up since they only activate with 1,2 and 3. Where could this valve be sending water to?? 4 also has the water filter for some reason. I'm not sure if that means anything. Thank you!

Comment: Probably an old drip irrigation system that is hard to see in bushes or ivy. Drip and soaker systems are often installed with filters due to ease of clogging small orifices on mini heads and drippers.

Comment: If you hear the water running, follow the sound.  Or let it run for a while and eventually you'll see some flooding somewhere.  Might be a drip zone per above comment.  Might be a sprinkler head firmly stuck shut for some reason, eg covered by grass or rocks.  Might be a broken hose ... if so the water will eventually trickle up and be visible.

Comment: My bet is a broken pipe. Let it run while wandering around listening for buried sprinkler heads, gurgling etc.  Also, look for water pooling someplace.  If you can hear water running with valve 4 open, it's going somewhere. Sprinkler heads that have been grown over by grass can be especially hard to find.

Comment: I agree with the above comments the filter makes sense for a drip system as they plug up easily if not filtered. Turn zone 4 on and check  around later